# Examples of semimodules over some semiring where the additive identity of the semimodule and the semiring are equal?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm looking for examples of semimodules over semirings such that the additive identity of the semimodule is the same as the additive identity of the semiring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb R$ form a semimodule with usual addition and scalar multiplication with $0$ as identity.